# Kubernetes isn't allowing me to create a pod with securityContext runAsUser

Tags: kubernetes, istio

**Summary:**

I have pods with `security context: runAsUser: 1337` that fail to start due to being disallowed by policy. I have altered admission-control to no success (as suggested [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/45324#issuecomment-299134709)
 and [here](https://github.com/istio/istio/issues/324#issuecomment-304116794))

What else do I need to force through this kind of security context?

**Details**

I'm working through the https://istio.io/docs/samples/bookinfo.html example to start porting over to istio.

I have a deployment named `details-v1` (see below) from which a replica set and pod have been created. The pod is stuck in pending.

```
NAME                                      READY     STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
details-v1-3207759430-nt9tt               0/2       Pending   0          34m
```

`describe` on the pod shows the cause of the error:

```
FailedValidation    Error validating pod details-v1-3207759430-nt9tt.azs-master from api, ignoring: spec.initContainers[1].securityContext.privileged: Forbidden: disallowed by policy
```

In order to get this far, I have already made changes to the kube-apiserver:

```
/usr/local/bin/kube-apiserver \
  --admission-control=NamespaceLifecycle,LimitRanger,ServiceAccount,ResourceQuota \
  --allow-privileged=true \
```

Deployment:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  annotations:
    deployment.kubernetes.io/revision: "1"
    kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration: |
      {"apiVersion":"extensions/v1beta1","kind":"Deployment","metadata":{"annotations":{},"creationTimestamp":null,"name":"details-v1","namespace":"azs-master"},"spec":{"replicas":1,"strategy":{},"template":{"metadata":{"annotations":{"alpha.istio.io/sidecar":"injected","alpha.istio.io/version":"jenkins@ubuntu-16-04-build-12ac793f80be71-0.1.6-dab2033","pod.beta.kubernetes.io/init-containers":"[{\"args\":[\"-p\",\"15001\",\"-u\",\"1337\"],\"image\":\"docker.io/istio/init:0.1\",\"imagePullPolicy\":\"Always\",\"name\":\"init\",\"securityContext\":{\"capabilities\":{\"add\":[\"NET_ADMIN\"]}}},{\"args\":[\"-c\",\"sysctl -w kernel.core_pattern=/tmp/core.%e.%p.%t \\u0026\\u0026 ulimit -c unlimited\"],\"command\":[\"/bin/sh\"],\"image\":\"alpine\",\"imagePullPolicy\":\"Always\",\"name\":\"enable-core-dump\",\"securityContext\":{\"privileged\":true}}]"},"creationTimestamp":null,"labels":{"app":"details","version":"v1"}},"spec":{"containers":[{"image":"istio/examples-bookinfo-details-v1","imagePullPolicy":"IfNotPresent","name":"details","ports":[{"containerPort":9080}],"resources":{}},{"args":["proxy","sidecar","-v","2"],"env":[{"name":"POD_NAME","valueFrom":{"fieldRef":{"fieldPath":"metadata.name"}}},{"name":"POD_NAMESPACE","valueFrom":{"fieldRef":{"fieldPath":"metadata.namespace"}}},{"name":"POD_IP","valueFrom":{"fieldRef":{"fieldPath":"status.podIP"}}}],"image":"docker.io/istio/proxy_debug:0.1","imagePullPolicy":"Always","name":"proxy","resources":{},"securityContext":{"runAsUser":1337},"volumeMounts":[{"mountPath":"/etc/certs","name":"istio-certs","readOnly":true}]}],"volumes":[{"name":"istio-certs","secret":{"secretName":"istio.default"}}]}}},"status":{}}
  creationTimestamp: 2017-06-23T13:30:00Z
  generation: 1
  labels:
    app: details
    version: v1
  name: details-v1
  namespace: azs-master
  resourceVersion: "29678612"
  selfLink: /apis/extensions/v1beta1/namespaces/azs-master/deployments/details-v1
  uid: 0eacea4a-5818-11e7-af0e-0a55ca98bb17
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: details
      version: v1
  strategy:
    rollingUpdate:
      maxSurge: 1
      maxUnavailable: 1
    type: RollingUpdate
  template:
    metadata:
      annotations:
        alpha.istio.io/sidecar: injected
        alpha.istio.io/version: jenkins@ubuntu-16-04-build-12ac793f80be71-0.1.6-dab2033
        pod.alpha.kubernetes.io/init-containers: '[{"name":"init","image":"docker.io/istio/init:0.1","args":["-p","15001","-u","1337"],"resources":{},"imagePullPolicy":"Always","securityContext":{"capabilities":{"add":["NET_ADMIN"]}}},{"name":"enable-core-dump","image":"alpine","command":["/bin/sh"],"args":["-c","sysctl
          -w kernel.core_pattern=/tmp/core.%e.%p.%t \u0026\u0026 ulimit -c unlimited"],"resources":{},"imagePullPolicy":"Always","securityContext":{"privileged":true}}]'
        pod.beta.kubernetes.io/init-containers: '[{"name":"init","image":"docker.io/istio/init:0.1","args":["-p","15001","-u","1337"],"resources":{},"imagePullPolicy":"Always","securityContext":{"capabilities":{"add":["NET_ADMIN"]}}},{"name":"enable-core-dump","image":"alpine","command":["/bin/sh"],"args":["-c","sysctl
          -w kernel.core_pattern=/tmp/core.%e.%p.%t \u0026\u0026 ulimit -c unlimited"],"resources":{},"imagePullPolicy":"Always","securityContext":{"privileged":true}}]'
      creationTimestamp: null
      labels:
        app: details
        version: v1
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: istio/examples-bookinfo-details-v1
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        name: details
        ports:
        - containerPort: 9080
          protocol: TCP
        resources: {}
        terminationMessagePath: /dev/termination-log
      - args:
        - proxy
        - sidecar
        - -v
        - "2"
        env:
        - name: POD_NAME
          valueFrom:
            fieldRef:
              apiVersion: v1
              fieldPath: metadata.name
        - name: POD_NAMESPACE
          valueFrom:
            fieldRef:
              apiVersion: v1
              fieldPath: metadata.namespace
        - name: POD_IP
          valueFrom:
            fieldRef:
              apiVersion: v1
              fieldPath: status.podIP
        image: docker.io/istio/proxy_debug:0.1
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        name: proxy
        resources: {}
        securityContext:
          runAsUser: 1337
        terminationMessagePath: /dev/termination-log
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /etc/certs
          name: istio-certs
          readOnly: true
      dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
      restartPolicy: Always
      securityContext: {}
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 30
      volumes:
      - name: istio-certs
        secret:
          defaultMode: 420
          secretName: istio.default
status:
  conditions:
  - lastTransitionTime: 2017-06-23T13:30:00Z
    lastUpdateTime: 2017-06-23T13:30:00Z
    message: Deployment has minimum availability.
    reason: MinimumReplicasAvailable
    status: "True"
    type: Available
  observedGeneration: 1
  replicas: 1
  unavailableReplicas: 1
  updatedReplicas: 1
```

Kubernetes server version: 1.5.6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Pending state indicates that this was blocked by the Kubelet, which also needs the `--allow-priveleged` flag.